# How can i apply onClick only on my upper component?

Tags: reactjs

I need some help for this : How can i apply my upper div (onClick) only on my ResizableBox component ?

```
<div onClick={() => {
      isSelected();
    }}>
      <ResizableBox
        width={box.width}
        height={box.height}
        boxId={box.id}
        style={
          getStyles(box.left, box.top, collectData.isDragging, isBoxSelected, box.border)
        }
        onContextMenu={(e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          setIsPopMenuOpened(!isPopMenuOpened);
        }}
      >
        <div
          onDoubleClick={onDoubleClick}
          className={cn({ "Drag-hide-grab": !draggable, "Drag-active": collectData.isDragging })}
          ref={drag}
          draggable={draggable}
        >
          <PopMenu
            visible={isPopMenuOpened}
            box={box}
            onClose={() => setIsPopMenuOpened(false)}
            setCopy={setCopy}
          ></PopMenu>
          {children({ isDragging: collectData.isDragging })}
        </div>
      </ResizableBox>
    </div>
```

I tried to put a second onClick on my PopMenu component but it does not work, same for putting onClick in ResizableBox component.

Comment: What is your problem? The `onClick` doesn't trigger or it triggers on everything?

Comment: It triggers on everything, and i want it to trigger only on ResizableBox

Comment: I need more information. What does this `onclick` is supposed to do? Are you talking about the `onClick` on the `div`?

Comment: The onClick is doing an event who select a box (like Word) and i want to onClick work when i click on my box and not on the popupmenu, yes i talk about the onClick on the div.

Answer (score 0):

If you add  `e.stopPropagation();` in your onClick function, i believe that should solve the issue. It will prevent the children to be clicked as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since the first `div` is only wrapping `ResizableBox`, I would delete the `div` and put the `onClick` directly into `ResizableBox`. Adding `event.stopPropagation();` so it does not trigger on other elements.

```
  <ResizableBox
    onClick={ event => {
      event.stopPropagation();
      if (event.target.nodeName != 'PopMenu'){
      isSelected();}
    }}
  </ResizableBox>
```

Comment: @Rayane modified my answer, is it better?

Comment: That's the same :(

Comment: can you tell me, for every possible action: -What you're doing -How the code behaves - How it should behave